# Android viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to create an app with one activity and 3 fragments in it. Pages don't need to be dynamically created but its a plus. My question is: do I need a separate fragment for every view or I can reuse one with different view?I've read the android tutorial here https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager 
for view pager and it left me with that impression. Its an important project. I am a noob so pls explain for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want 3 full screen fragments.  Use a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

`my_fragment.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

`MyPagerAdapter.java`:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

This will allow swiping right or left to switch between the fragments.  You will have to use a `TabLayout`, bottom navigation, buttons, or some other way to switch between them besides swiping. I'll leave that for you to figure out ;)